# Prove that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$.Assume that $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a $C^{2}$ map such that at any point $z \in \Omega$ either $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z)=0$ or $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z)=0$ holds. Prove that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a holomorphic function.(for definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z)$ you can see [definition of a Holomorphic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2378703/frac-partial-f-partial-bar-z-equiv-0-as-a-definition-for-a-holomorphic-f))

I try to solve this problem but I'm not sure that my way is right. I first show that if we define
$$U=\{ z| z \in \Omega :\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z)=0 \} \ \ \ \ \ V=\{ z| z \in \Omega \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z)=0\}$$
then U and V are open sets from that f is $C^{2}$.(Is it true?) for points in U we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z)=0$ is constant and so holomorphic.for points In $V$ we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z)=0$ and we have directly from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}$ that f is holomorphic. then from that f is holomorphic and $C^{2}$ it is easy to see that we have Cauchy–Riemann equations for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and so it is holomorphic in $V$ and so it's holomorphic in whole of $\Omega$. But I think maybe my way is not true because I don't use the connectedness of $\Omega$ and I think maybe we have some problem in $U\cap V$ .

Comment: 'If we are in $U$' is not a precise term. Some points $z$ may be in $U$ and some in $V$.

Comment: Actually $U$ and $V$ are _closed_ sets...

Comment: Yes they are closed but I think they are open too. so if this is right we can conclude that $\Omega=U or \Omega=V$! and then proof be trivial... but I think I'm wrong.